# Почему невалидный файл успешно проходит валидацию (C#)?

Tags: c#, xml, валидация, xsd

Всем доброго времени суток!
Столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу правильно подключить валидацию xml файла через xsd схему. Проблема в том, что у меня успешно проходит валидацию файл, который не соответствует схеме. Надеюсь, что знающие люди смогут подсказать, где я совершил ошибку.

Схема:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="books">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="book">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>

              <xs:element name="name">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:minLength value="1" />
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>

              <xs:element name="author">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:minLength value="1" />
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>

              <xs:element name="price" type="xs:positiveInteger" />

              <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>        
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name='unique_field_id'>
      <xs:selector xpath='xs:book' />
      <xs:field xpath='id' />
    </xs:unique>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

XML файл, который успешно проходит валидацию:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<books xmlns="localhost" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="/XML/ BooksListSchema.xsd">
  <book xmlns="">
    <name></name>
    <author>Author 3</author>
    <price>3200</price>
    <id>1003</id>
  </book>
  <book xmlns="">
    <name>Book 4</name>
    <author>Author 4</author>
    <price>-3000</price>
    <id>547</id>
  </book>
  <book xmlns="">
    <name>Book 1</name>
    <author>Athour 11</author>
    <price>1111</price>
    <id>547</id>
  </book>
</books>
```

Код, который проводит проверку файла на валидность:

```
private void ValidaionFile (HttpPostedFileBase fileData) {
            string SchemaPath = Server.MapPath("~/XML/BooksListSchema.xsd");

            var xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.Load(fileData.InputStream);

            xDoc.Schemas.Add("", SchemaPath);
            xDoc.Validate(ValidationEventHandler);
        }

        private static void ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e) {
            XmlSeverityType type = XmlSeverityType.Warning;
            if (Enum.TryParse<XmlSeverityType>("Error", out type)) {
                if (type == XmlSeverityType.Error) throw new Exception(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Гм, любопытно. Валидатор Visual Studio тоже не показывает ошибки. Но если убрать определение пространства имен: `xmlns="localhost"`, то валидация начинает работать как надо. Я весьма удивлен, ведь с неймспейсом, по идее, документ тоже невалиден.

Comment: Если убрать xmlns="localhost", то в самой студии подчеркиваютя элементы и говорится, что books имеет невалидные элементы book, даже, если они валидны. Если честно, я не доконца понял, что должно быть в xmlns и какую он играет роль, поэтому добавил localhost.

Comment: Если неймспейс убрать, то валидация работает корректно. Обратите внимание: в схеме разрешен лишь один дочерний элемент `book`.

Comment: убрал неймспейс и указал, что дочерних элементов book может быть неограниченное количество (name="book" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"). Но самое забавное, что валидация все еще проходит успешно (например, заливаю файл, где price имеет отрицательное значение и он проходит валидацию), но в самой студии я вижу подчеркнутые элементы, и надпись, что они невалидны, если смотреть на схему (ругается на отрицательное значение price).

Comment: Ну, теперь дебаггер в руки. `ValidationEventHandler` вызывается? Может, исключение глотается где-то выше по коду?

Comment: Кстати, код в этом хендлере у вас весьма странный. Должно быть что-то вроде `if (e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error)` - не?

Comment: с хендлером еще до конца не разобрался, т.к. только начал в целом изучать xml и работу с ним в C#. Так же волшебным (для меня) образом валидация заработала. Если пустой name, author или отрицательный price, то вываливается исключение. Только уникальность id не проверяется, полагаю дело уже в xsd, как-то не так указал проверку на уникальность. Случайно не знаете в чем тут проблема?

Comment: Это надо бы задать отдельным вопросом. В селекторе должно быть: `xpath='book'` - без `xs`. Потому что xs - это префикс пространства имен самой схемы, он не имеет отношения к проверяемому документу.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пожалуй опишу что и как подробно.

Начнем с того, что логика валидатора .NET, немного отличается от привычной логики, например, SAX-парсера. В частности, **если при валидации среди загруженных схем не обнаружено пространство имен, указанное в элементе XML, то валидатор игнорирует данный элемент и считает его, корректным**. Это не лишено некоторого смысла, но может сбивать с толку. К сожалению, никаких упоминаний о таком поведении в документации я не нашел, утверждение основано на практическом использовании.

В вашем случае вы загружаете элемент `<books xmlns="localhost" ...` у которого явно указано пространство имен. Однако при загрузке схемы `xDoc.Schemas.Add("", SchemaPath);`, вы загрузили ее без указания пространства имен, поэтому валидатор проигнорировал элемент `books` и его содержимое при проверке (базовая валидация структуры XML происходит при загрузке документа).

Для того чтобы валидация заработала есть два пути:

1. Оставить схему и ее загрузку без изменений и удалить из проверяемого XML все упоминания пространств имен `xmlns`.
2. Оставить исходный файл как есть, изменить определение схемы на такое

   ```
   <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      targetNamespace="localhost"
      xmlns="localhost"
      elementFormDefault="qualified">
   ```

   и изменить загрузку схемы в валидатор:

   ```
   xDoc.Schemas.Add("localhost", SchemaPath);
   ```

Не в даваясь в подробности определения схемы, приведенный фрагмент кода проверки XML работает корректно и кидает все положенные исключения.